# How to Make Category tree Auto expand the assigned subcategory tree in edit product form?

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, adminform, category-tree, jslayout

I'm using Magento 2.4.1 and have 4 levels category when editing a product in cms it really cumbersome when I need to locate the hierarchy of my product categories because when it first loads it only expands to the second level not expanding to which the category is checked. for example:

[image]

what I want is to have like this, it will auto-expand the tree to the location of the subcategory that product is assigned when load the product edit page:

[image]